# How many times does Michael travel through time machine?

Tags: plot-explanation, paycheck

In *[Paycheck (2003)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338337/)*, Michael perfectly used all of the 20 items in the envelope.

[image]

Remember the English proverb

> **Practice makes perfect.**

How many times does Michael travel through the time machine to gain a grip on the 20 items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Micheal never time travelled in Paycheck. Infact, no one did same in this movie. Machine reverse engineered by made him able see the future but it cannot be used to travel in time.

Plot from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paycheck_(film))

> Jennings realizes he must have built this device based on Dekker's invention and, on realizing the horrors that will come, prepared the envelope, using the forecasts from the machine to allow his future self to return to Allcom and destroy the machine. Furthermore, as Rethrick discovers, Jennings rigged the device to malfunction, preventing Rethrick from anticipating Jennings' actions.

Comment: That's certainly and interesting detail to point out. It still doesn't adress the specific question too much in that it could now just ask "how many times did he *look* into the future then?".

Comment: It was not clear in movie  how many he saw the future. His memory was erased for duration when he saw future and plan. He was always under observation, so it is not possible that he saw multiple time .